# I would like to know how to use $$eval from Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I can not use $$ eval well.

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: chrome ,args: [chromeArgs]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/', {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    var links = await page.evaluate(() => {
        var hreflist = [];
        var tags = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tags, (tag)=>{
            hreflist.push(tag.textContent);
        });
        return hreflist;
    });
    console.log(util.inspect(links, false, null));
    browser.close();
})();
```

I would like to do the same thing as the source code written above.

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: chrome ,args: [chromeArgs]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/', {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    var links = await page.$$eval('p', list => {
        list.map(data => {
            data.textContent
        })
    });

    console.log(util.inspect(links, false, null));
    browser.close();
})();
```

The execution result of $$eval() is undefined.

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.10.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args
I saw the official document.
However, we can not confirm the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return the value. this will work

```
var links = await page.$$eval('p', list => list.map(data => data.textContent));
```